# RSquared Mathematica Excel incoherence

Tags: fitting

I've done a NonLinearRegression with this data

```
{{0.245, 0.0917011}, {0.25, 0.0894304}, {0.25, 0.108895}, 
 {0.25, 0.111991}, {0.251, 0.0898849}, {0.251, 0.107753},
 {0.254, 0.114524}, {0.254, 0.121882}, {0.255, 0.130478},
 {0.255, 0.186865}, {0.256, 0.108817}, {0.256, 0.128742},
 {0.256, 0.131999}, {0.257, 0.150797}}
```

The model is a simply parabola:

```
y=a x^2+b x +c
```

The coefficiets are:

```
 a= 317.459
 b=-154.723
 c= 18.9415
```

Then I've done the same with Excel and the coefficients are the same, but `R^2` is not the same.
In Mathematica I've got `R^2=0.97` and Excel tells me `R^2=0.45`.
Why there is this incoherence?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/R$20squared/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/Ja_Igz6MzQk/2U5-YTA6UfQJ) will be useful.

Comment: Plus, correct me if I am wrong, but you will get different values of R depending on the data - whether it is a sample or the whole population.

Comment: We had an earlier question on this, but I can't find it anymore. I believe the answer was that in a non linear model fit rsquared has a different meaning and that LinearModelFit should be used in this case.

Comment: @b.gatessucks Your link does not work for me. Perhaps it depends on being logged in into google groups?

Comment: @b.gatessucks Your link is very useful. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Sjoerd C. de Vries It doesen't work with ipad, but with my notebook it works well.

Comment: That was what I was using indeed.

Comment: I think I found the earlier refernce. It was [this MathGroup question](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/Ja_Igz6MzQk). The explanation given there seems to be complete.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries It's the same link, I don't know why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: @b.gatessucks Probably an iPad issue as Mary surmized. For one reason or another when the link includes a search action (as yours does) I get just a standard google groups home screen (and I repeated quite a few times to be sure). My link leads directly to the topic and works on my iPad. I just tested yours on my office desktop and it works there.

Answer (score 8):

`lm=LinearModelFit[data,{1,x,x^2},x]` yields the same coefficient estimates and the R^2 for this model coincides with Excel, i.e. Excel uses linear regression model

```
lm["RSquared"]
```

yields:

```
0.454452
```

Comment: thanks I agree with your comment. In fact I've done a linear regression no a non Linear model.